# Creating checkbox control with two or more checkbox button

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, user-controls, checkbox

I am having a requirement to create a page which contains dynamic check box controls. I am handling this by adding controls to Placeholder in page_init event.

Now, i have to change the controls to render in this way

[image: Expected rendering of checkbox list]

One option contains 3 checkboxes and first 2 checkboxes are disabled and gives a kind of suggestion to the user to select the 3rd checkbox

How can i achieve this kind of requirement?

Comment: Does your question means that the number of check boxes are decided at runtime or you need exactly 3 checkboxes???

Comment: Yes, check boxes are added dynamically to the aspx placeholder by adding checkboxlist  and binding data to it. I need every option to have 3 checkboxes

Comment: Ok, according to the image in your question, one row is the user control and each row s added dynamically, isn t it???

Comment: Actually i didnt completed the implementation, currently i am able to add checkbox list dynamically and bind data to it.if u consider the image as a table with 3 rows and 4 columns, now the page is rendering 3rd and 4th columns, i need suggestions on completing the implementation as per image

Comment: But your question s still not clear enough for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx) control: it's good when is a need to dynamically create group of same controls.

Comment: Can i add a repeater control dynamically and define item template during page_init event?

Comment: Why add repeater control dynamically? Add repeater, set item template and define datasource. Then on page_init (or when you need it) fill datasource and rest of job will do repeater control. Of course you can mess with programatically adding controls... I think it is worng way for asp (most of the time), link for you, if you still need it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1.aspx

Comment: I need to add controls dynamically as all the options are coming from DB. Even number of checkboxes is also coming from DB

Comment: So repeater perfectly fits: from db you get random number of lines, repeater will render each line by provided template. (BTW it's possible to use nested repeater http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/AspNetNestedRepeaters.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're having a problem with exactly, but to disable a `CheckBox` you just have to set the `Enabled` property to `false`.

Comment: Its not the problem of enabling or disabling, my question is how can i render the checkboxlist which contains 3 checkboxes for every options and first 2 checkboxes are disabled

Answer (score 0):

You can use a GridView with three checkbox columns:

http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=5187857

Comment: I cannot use any repeater control as it renders them row by row, but my requirement is to place the check boxes horizontally aligned

Comment: @Sandeep: With css you can arrange your controls in repeater as you need - vertically, horizontally, left, right, etc...